# Why top values in % are not responding in Google chrome while it does in firefox?

Tags: css, google-chrome

I'm designing a website in which I have a logo which need to be positioned in center.For that I gave the code as following.

```
#logo{
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

Logo is inside the another div having id `cont`.Code for `cont` is as follows.

```
#cont{
    height: 80vh;
    width: 80vw;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

The HTML code is simple and as follows.

```
<div>
    <div id="cont">
        <img src="./log.png" alt="logo" id="logo"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now the code is working as expected in firefox.The logo is centered without any issues.But in chrome it is not working properly.I inspected the logo in chrome and I observed that `top : 50%` value is not responsive in chrome.While `left : 50%` is responsive as expected.
If I give `top : 50vh` it is responding.It is only unresponsive for % values.But I need to use % values in top.How can I do that and why this problem is occuring?

Comment: You should add your HTML and couple the CSS in a snippet in your post, then we can help you better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works in chrome, and all the code you wrote should work in chrome, have you remembered to refreshed the cache?

however, the way you write your code is not following best practices. Absolute position should be avoided where possible. I have Recreated the code here.

```css
#logo{
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

#logo img {
  max-height: 50%;
}

#cont{
    border: 2px solid red;

    height: 80vh;
    width: 80vw;

    margin: 5vh auto;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div id="cont">
      <div id="logo">
          <img src="https://media.sproutsocial.com/uploads/2017/02/10x-featured-social-media-image-size.png"
           alt="logo" />
      </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: @VasuCh great, if you decide to post another question regarding css please @ me in the comments and i will try to help :)